# when select image that wide != 500 px., why ie7 not show aleart message?

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer

.....................................................................................................................................................................

when select image that wide != 500 px., why ie7 not show aleart message ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="offer_image_1" type="file" id="offer_image_1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;   // for check wide and height image
$("#offer_image_1").change(function(e) {
    var offer_image_1, img;
    if ((offer_image_1 = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            if (this.width != '500')
            {
            alert("not width 500 px.");
            }
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(offer_image_1);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Because it's IE ... It's meant to break your code!

Comment: Maybe try `(this.width !== '500')`. And shouldn't you put the selected image in the newly created img before you try to get the width out of it?

Comment: IE7 has no support for the File API, and the change event probably isn't fired, as IE need to have the onpropertychange event handler set for file inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
  if (this.width() != '500')
  {
      alert("not width 500 px.");
  }
```